# Rails 3 nested attributes: How can I assign a matching record to the parent model instead of creating a new record every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Here's the basic setup:

I have an `Order` model. An `Order` has one `Address` and it `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address`.

I have a basic order form where I ask a user to input her address. This is handled with `nested_fields_for`. Everything works great - new addresses are validated and assigned nicely.

However, the problem is that **it creates a new `Address` every time**, even if an `Address` already exists with identical attributes.

I would like to modify the behavior so that if the user-inputted address matches all the attributes for an existing `Address`, the order assigns the *existing* `Address` to itself rather than creating a new one.

The methods I have tried are:

1. In the controller, try to find an existing Address record with the nested attributes (`params[:order][:address_attributes]`). If a match exists, delete all the nested attributes and replace them with `params[:order][:address_id]`.
2. Don't use `nested_attributes_for` at all and instead override the `address=` method in the model, then just use the controller to create a new `Address` based on the parameters and then hand it off to the model.

Both of these solutions seem various degrees of messy. Could somebody please enlighten me on whether this is a controller or model responsibility, and perhaps suggest an elegant way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm asking this as a survey of good ways to do this, I figured I'd offer the solution I'm currently using as well as a basis for comment.

**In the Controller:**

```
@new_address = Address.new( params[:order][:address] )
@order.address = new_address
@order.update_attributes( params[:order] )
```

**In the Model:**

```
def address=( address )
    return unless address and address.is_a? Address

    duplicate_address = Address.where( address_1: address.address_1, 
                                       address_2: address.address_2,
                                       [etc. etc.] ).first

    if duplicate_address
        self.address_id = duplicate_address.id
    else
        address.save
        self.address_id = address.id
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # [..]

  before_save :replace_existing_address!

  def replace_existing_address!
    db_address = Address.where(:city => self.address.city,
                :street => self.address.street,
                :number => self.address.number).first
    self.address = db_address if db_address
  end

end
```

Comment: Yes, this is very similar to what I overrode the attribute setter with. I like this approach, though I might make it a `before_create` callback so that it doesn't query the database every time an order is modified. I'd like to see what other methods people use before accepting, but this seems to be a perfectly good solution.

Comment: also the name is not perfect, maybe `reuse_address!`, I can't think right now

Answer (score 0):

I it's truly a :has_one relationship as you say and not a :has_many, you don't need to explicitly assign the address like you do in your own answer. That's what accepts_nested_attributes is for, after all. This line by itself should work:

```
@order.update_attributes( params[:order] )
```

That should create a new address if none exists, and update an existing one.

Your solution may work, but it a) doesn't take advantage of accepts_nested_attributes and b) will leave lots of orphaned addresses in your database.

Comment: Good point about the orphaned addresses, but how does this solve the original problem, which is that this approach will lead to multiple identical addresses (in all but ID) in the database? As far as I know, `accepts_nested_attributes` does not check to see if a record exists with identical attributes, it only checks to see if a record exists with identical ID. Since the addresses don't have an ID at the time they are created through the order form, this will lead to a new address every time.